# Connecting from VB to Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I’m trying to connect to my access DB, run a query, and do something with the result set. Can someone please share a short explanation to how this can be accomplished?

I'm using Access 2007 with VB7

Comment: don't say "vb7" - it's "vb.net" now. If you really want to use "vb7", that would imply .Net 1.1. Is this accurate, or you using a later version of .Net (2.0, 3.5, etc)? New .Net 1.1 development is pretty rare these days. I ask, because 2.0 added some things that would significantly change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

sample code snippet:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim connectionString As String
        Dim cnn As OleDbConnection
        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=yourdatabasename.mdb;"
        cnn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Try
            cnn.Open()
            MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
            cnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

[You can look for more examples on this link.](http://vb.net-informations.com/ado.net-dataproviders/ado.net-oledbconnection.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Best place I can think to start is looking up the System.Data Library on MSDN. You may want to focus on OLEDB constructors. HTH.